# Using more than one condition in a CASE expression

Tags: field-calculator

I am currently trying to update the attribute "barcode" of layer that has many features.

If the value is null or "0" then I take the value from barcode 2.

I wrote the code bellow: The first condition (value is null) works well, just the other does is ignored apparently, any idea why this happens?

```
CASE WHEN ("barcode"is null  or '0') THEN 
 "Joined layer_barcode_2 "  ELSE "barcode" END
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if expressions worked like speech but I'm afraid they don't. So, you need to "say":

```
"barcode" is null or "barcode" = '0'
```